# BBPress changing default group activity

Tags: filters, bbpress, customization

Dear WordPress community,

I am pretty new to WordPress and I am running into an issue with **BBPress**, when I open a group there is a small pulldown on the right side of the page where I am able to change the view of the group activity. By default, this pulldown is filled with "*--Everything--*", I want it to select and load "*Updates*" instead of "*--Everything--*" as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

Is there anybody able to push me in the right direction for this issue?

Best regards,

Kai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a bit more I found this plugin:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/bp-activity-filter/

It will let you alter these settings without modifying the plugin itself.

Hope this will help other users in the future that will land here through a search.